# Need help to write expression in ssrs to calculate a field on condition basis

Tags: reporting-services

i want to create field C from field A and field B the logic i want to use to calculate C field is this C=(A-(B*.05))<0,0 else value.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you show us your code? What exactly doesn't work for you? Error message?

Comment: thanks the eror was fixed

Answer (score 0):

did you want an expression in a cell or a separate column for you dataset?

as a simple expression

```
=iif((fields!a.value - (fields!b.value * 0.05)) <0,0,(fields!a.value - (fields!b.value * 0.05)))
```

If you want it as a calculated column then simply right click on your dataset and select

> Add Calculated Field  , give it a suitable name and use the same expression above.

You should be able to then use this column in your report like any other column.